# Set default subdirectory page in IIS 6

Tags: webserver, iis

I'd like to set the default page of a directory under /inetpub/wwwroot to something other than 'index.html'. Using Apache and .htaccess I'd use the 'DirectoryIndex' statement. How can I do this in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IIS Manager, right-click the folder you want to change the default document for.  Click Properties, click Documents Tab.

Check-mark "Enable default content page" and "Add" the page you want as your default.

[image: IIS Default Document]

Comment: Perfect - I found this already but a concise answer nonetheless :)